# Find solution of recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the solution of the recurrence relation of
$$x_n^2=x_{n-1}^2+6x_{n-2}^2+7^n$$
with $x_0=x_1=1$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you at least generated a number of terms in a spreadsheet?  Do you know how to solve linear recurrence relations using the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: What about substituting $a_n = x_n^2$ and solving for $a_n$? There's no point in keeping the square

Comment: Haven't thought about it yet @Jakobian, I'll try it to see what happens.

Comment: [Recursion solving techniques](https://www.math.kth.se/math/student/courses/5B1203/F/200304/linrek.pdf)

Comment: Your link does not open ("Sorry, this service is temporarily unavailable").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comments and with quite a few shortcuts (i.e. wolfram links), substituting $a_n=x_n^2$
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+7^n \tag{1}$$
this also means
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+6a_{n-1}+7^{n+1} \tag{2}$$
we multiply $(1)$ by 7
$$7a_n=7a_{n-1}+42a_{n-2}+7^{n+1} \tag{3}$$
now subtract $(3)$ from $(2)$
$$a_{n+1}-7a_n=a_{n}+6a_{n-1}-7a_{n-1}-42a_{n-2} \iff \\
a_{n+1}-8a_n+a_{n-1}+42a_{n-2}=0$$
which is a linear homogeneous recurrence with [characteristic polynomial](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial)
$$x^3-8x^2+x+42=0$$
[with roots](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-8x%5E2%2Bx%2B42%3D0) $-2, 3, 7$ and general solution
$$a_n=A(-2)^n+B3^n+C7^n \tag{4}$$
Now, from $x_0=x_1=1 \Rightarrow a_0=a_1=1$ and from $(1) \Rightarrow a_2=56$ leading to
$$a_0=1=A+B+C$$
$$a_1=1=-2A+3B+7C$$
$$a_2=56=4A+9B+49C$$
[solving this system of linear equations leads](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%3DA%2BB%2BC,%201%3D-2A%2B3B%2B7C,%2056%3D4A%2B9B%2B49C) to
$$a_n=\frac{67}{45}(-2)^n-\frac{37}{20}3^n+\frac{49}{36}7^n \tag{5}$$
(can be validated [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5Bn%5D%3Da%5Bn-1%5D%2B6a%5Bn-2%5D%2B7%5En,%20a%5B0%5D%3D1,%20a%5B1%5D%3D1) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B67%7D%7B45%7D*(-2)%5En-%5Cfrac%7B37%7D%7B20%7D*3%5En%2B%5Cfrac%7B49%7D%7B36%7D*7%5En)) and
$$x_n=\sqrt{\frac{67}{45}(-2)^n-\frac{37}{20}3^n+\frac{49}{36}7^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $a_n=x_n^2$ then:

$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+7^n$$

Which we will call equation $1$. Suppose $a_{n}=c7^n$ is one solution to the recurrence above (a particular solution). Then,

$$c7^{n}=c7^{n-1}+6c7^{n-2}+7^{n}$$

Subtracting this equation from equation $1$ gives,

$$\left(a_{n}-c7^n \right)=\left(a_{n-1}-c7^{n-1} \right)+6 \left(a_{n-2}-c7^{n-2} \right)$$

Letting $b_{n}=a_{n}-c7^{n}$ gives,

$$b_{n}=b_{n-1}+6b_{n-2}$$